# How to use footnote for shared affiliation in ACM latex?

Tags: latex, acm

I'm using `\documentclass{sig-alternate}` to write an article. The thing is, we should use `\author` and then add `\alignauthor`, `\affil`, and `\email` for each author. Two authors has affiliation1 and the others has affiliation2 and I want to save space by creating a footnote. How can I do this? 
Note that the new format doesn't let me use `sharedaffiliation` as used by many users before.

Comment: Wouldn't [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com) be a better place for this question?